# onApply is not being called if state of validationTextBox is error - Dojo

Tags: validation, dojo, listener

I have a validationTextBox that I have connected an onApply listener to. Whenever I change the value in the validationTextBox to a string that would cause the state to be equal to error, the onApply is not being called. Is this behavior a normal behavior in Dojo? Any suggestion how I can workaround it if it's the case?

Comment: I think you are confusing onApply listner with onChange listener.

Comment: Why? I tried onChange, and it's not being called anyway, even if the state of the ValidationTextBox is not Error. Can you suggest how I can use onChange here?

Comment: can you add your code to the question so that we can understand where the error is.? With such a short and non-descriptive explanation it is very difficult to understand your problem.